# Range Number Generator

Tags: javascript, range, output

very new to JavaScript and having a small amount of trouble. My assignment is to click a button and it will generate a number between 1-20. Everything is working fine, minus the fact that the output from the function is being placed outside the text box. Any suggestions on how to get the output into the text box would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRNG(min, max) {
    return function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
    }
    d20 = getRNG(1, 20);
    function rollD20() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = d20();
    }
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="2" id="txtNumber" />
<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="rollD20()">Roll</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking a little further into this I'm trying to create an alert.

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20() {
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
  }
 if (txtNumber < 10) {
 alert("Failure");
 }
 else {
 alert("Success");
 }
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting the value to be placed inside the text box **input** (`#txtNumber`)
but instead you're targeting the DIV `#output`

Use:

```html
<script>
  function getRNG(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  function rollD20() {
    document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="2" id="txtNumber" />
  <div id="output"></div>
  <button onclick="rollD20();">Roll</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this stuff can be very frustrating at times!

Comment: you're welcome. Yes depends on coffeine sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, try to use this:

```
<script>
    function getRNG(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    function rollD20() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = getRNG(1, 20);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 problem, the problem is that you are setting the innerHTML value of the div (which is first 0 px width) and when you put your content in it expands to fit it's content.

The thing you want to do is assign the value of the txtNumber like this

```
 function rollD20() {
      document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = d20();
 }
```

Another node would be to change away from returning a function which returns a value and clean the code up a bit  (placing the function call inside of the rollD20 function)

```
 function getRNG(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
 }

 function rollD20() {
      document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
 }
```

All Combined to into a snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getRNG(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }

        function rollD20() {
            document.getElementById("txtNumber").value = getRNG(1, 20);
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="2" id="txtNumber" />
        <div id="output"></div>
        <button onclick="rollD20()">Roll</button>
    </body>
</html>
```